# How to specify fontmap in ghospcl

Tags: ghostscript

In ghostcript, you can use the -FONTMAP option to specify your font file. Is there such a possibility in ghostpcl. This option does not work. I am using ghostpcl 9.52 for Windows x64.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no fontmap for GhostPCL. The fontmap in Ghostscript is actually written in PostScript, so it can't work with GhostPCL.

For GhostPCL you get the standard fonts (which are not AGPL-compatible), everything else needs to be downloaded as part of the PCL.

Comment: Ok. Then the question is: I have an input pcl file `(9R(s0p11h0s0b4099T  !АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЫЭЮЯабвгдежзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщьъыэюя!` and a cour.pfa file containing the Cyrillic font I need. What do I need to do with this file for my pcl to convert to pdf successfully?

Comment: Well basically, you can't. A .pfa is a 'Printer Font Ascii', a PostScript format font. PCL only supports TrueType (and possibly some internal HP format) as downloadable font formats. You need to find a TrueType version of the font, then modify the PCL so that it creates a 'soft font', a downloadable version of the TrueType font, and embed the font in that part of hte PCL. And no, I can't tell you any way to do that, PCL is not my field; Ghostscript doesn't support PCL as it s PostScript interpreter.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was afraid of) So we will embed soft fonts when.